# what is the reason android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android

I get this error

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.widget.Toolbar
```

I use this import `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;`

this is code of toolbar

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    Toolbar tb=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.main);
    tb.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return (onOptionsItemSelected(item));
        }
    });
  //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   // return true;
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
```

Comment: Check two things. Check your layout file if you did use the support Toolbar class for the view. And then check if you set the toolbar as your supportActionBar (setSupportActionBar(toolbar)). Or you can paste the xml file and the whole activity source here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for many widgets Android provides two version. The one include on the support library and one part of the *native* support. If you are getting a ClassCastException is probably because you declared `Toolbar` in your layout instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Answer (score 2):

They are totally separate Java classes. You cannot cast a `java.lang.Double` to be a `com.moudiz.Restaurant`, for example.

`android.widget.Toolbar` is native to API Level 21 and higher. `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is a backport that is part of `appcompat-v7` and therefore is available going back to API Level 7.

If your app is using `appcompat-v7` in general (e.g., `AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat`), use `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. If your app is using the native action bar in general, use `android.widget.Toolbar`.